# change string to point to next character in function

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>


void change(char *str)
{
    (*str++);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "ABC";
    printf("before change %s \n",str);
    change(str);
    printf("after change %s \n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is

```
ABC
ABC
```

I want output to be

```
ABC
BC
```

I don't want to return string, str needs to be modified in change function; return type of change function should remain void. I don't know how to do this.

I did try to google it but i didn't find the solution.

Comment: You're passing the pointer *by value*, meaning the local variable `str` inside the `change` function is a *copy* of the original pointer. Changing copies won't change the original. Either return the new pointer, or search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: I just searched pointer by value and pointer by reference, cleared a lot of doubt about double pointers. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C if you want to change the value of an argument to a function, you need to take that argument by pointer.  And since here you are trying to change a pointer, it needs to be a pointer to a pointer:

```
void change(char **str)
{
    (*str)++;
}
```

Then:

```
change(&str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(*str++);` increments a local copy of `str`, not `str` from `main`. This is because C uses pass-by-value technique for function parameters.

You need to change your function to take a pointer to pointer, and pass a pointer to `str` in order to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

As we are in C would you need a pointer to a pointer.

I.e

```
void change(char **str) 
{
    *str = *str + 1;
}
```

Then

```
int main()
{
    char *str = "ABC";
    printf("before change %s \n",str);
    change(&str);
    printf("after change %s \n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/Ouo19v

Comment: "_double pointer_" might cause confusion and people might think of it as a pointer to `double`. I suggest using 'pointer to pointer' instead.